# How to calculate the amount automatically using javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my function

```
function  doMath() { 
   var counter; var nvalue; var amount;
   var price=100;
   nValue = document.getElementById("message").value;
   amount=(nvalue*price);
   document.getElementById("total").value=amount ;
}
```

My html

```
<input type="" name="message" id="message" onkeyup="doMath()"maxlength="60">message
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" maxlength="60"> amount
```

when user enter value into message field it should calculate the amount automatically and show it in amount field.

but while i entering the value it show NAN

its not calculating can anyone help me how to fix this .i m new to javascript

Comment: You have some inconsistencies with your variable names... `nvalue` --> `nValue`. Variable names are case sensitive.

Comment: No problem, you can delete your question since that's all it was.

Comment: For javascript development I suggest using firebug and javascript debugger. It would immediately tell you, that `nvalue` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared your variable as **nvalue** but used **nValue** instead.

```
   function  doMath() { 
       var nValue; var amount;
       var price=100;
       nValue = document.getElementById("message").value;
       amount=(nValue*price);
       document.getElementById("total").value=amount ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here:

```
  amount = (nvalue * price);
```

It should be:

```
  amount = (nValue * price);
```